# Problemas con Datepicker,cambia la fecha cuando se da click en cualquier parte de un modal

Tags: javascript, html5, jquery-datepicker

Tengo un problemilla con un Datepicker, el cual esta dentro de un modal,  el problema radica en que cuando abro el modal me carga los datos pre cargados, pero al momento de hacer click en cualquier parte de este,el Datepicker cambia a la fecha acual

adjunto código html

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Fecha</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fecha" id="fecha">
            <span id="fecha_error" class="badge badge-danger col-md-12 d-none">Debe Ingresar una fecha</span>
        </div>
```

adjunto código Javascript

```
 $('#fecha').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4', 
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
  });
```

si a alguno le ha pasado, favor auida!

Answer (score 0):

En el método `open` del diálogo:

```
$("#fecha").datepicker( "setDate" , "1/01/2020" );
```

Dónde `1/01/2020` es la fecha que quieres por defecto. Debes escuchar el evento que hace que se abra el dialogo y ahí  establecer la fecha por defecto o utilizar la función `open` si es un dialogo de Jquery.